# Missing Transaction on older Bither wallet on older computer

Tags: synchronization, bither

Please note I am not that technically savvy nor know that much about cryptocurrency. I am helping out a friend that (for disability reasons) cannot ask himself.

My friend purchased and has bitcoin he stored in an older laptop from around 2008 (unsure). He created a newer Bither wallet on a "newer" laptop he purchased around 2018/2019. He wanted to transfer the Bitcoin from the older Bither Wallet to the new one to "prep" it with the intention to sell all of it as it has become too much technology-wise to keep up with.

We tried to transfer the Bitcoin from the old Bither wallet via the "Send" feature and used the code of numbers that was (I assume) the account number of the newer Bither wallet. On the old wallet, it has a white dot noting the transaction. On the new Bither wallet, there is no indication of any transaction. We though we would wait to see if anything would happen and it has been a few months now and we do not know where the Bitcoin is anymore.

The old Bither wallet is version 1.4.5. It is running on a Dell laptop with Windows 7 Professional.

I am not sure of the newer Bither account. We live a few hours apart and would have to confirm with him the details on his end (which might take some time to obtain. Again, apologies and I hope for some patience for anyone helping us with this).

Also, I do not know what should be kept confidential so please let mw know if there is something I should not disclose here or post (the account "numbers," QR code etc.).

Thank you.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Yes, absolutely

First, please post the public keys of both the old and new wallets here.  We will be able to determine which has the Bitcoins, using those

Simply copy-pasting those numbers into blockchain.info will give the answer straightaway

These public keys are harmless to expose here, and it will likely be extremely difficult to obtain the private keys (which would allow anyone to steal the Bitcoins if exposed here)

NEVER post the private keys or the seed phrase, this will be tantamount to allowing the Bitcoins to be stolen. Whoever knows these numbers owns the Bitcoins

If there is disability involved, please have him take a picture of the public key QR codes. This will be good enough to determine which wallet has the Bitcoins, old or new

Comment: Are you asking for xpub of wallets? I don't think that should be posted here

Comment: Where can I find the public keys? Private keys (so I do not get them mixed up!)? Thank you for responding.

Comment: No problem!  All you need to do is post the public key (it will be a long series of numbers and letters, both capital and lowercase).  You can find these public keys next to the transaction itself in the wallet. As Prayank noted, there is no need to post the xpub key (though this is not dangerous, it is not recommended).  You can only obtain xpub and private key by digging around in settings, the public key should be easy to find under "transaction history" or "balance".  Your friend can take a picture of the "transaction history" screen if that is easier, on both the old and the new wallets